# PHP Warning: ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in

Tags: php, ftp

I don't know why i can't get a successful ftp_login.
All informations about my server are good but `$connect` fails.

Here is my code:

```
$connect = ftp_connect('myserver.1and1-data.host', 22, 5);
$login = ftp_login($connect, 'username', 'password');
```

I have this error:

```
PHP Warning:  ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in C:\\...
```

I have to put 22 as port or i have an error.

I've tried to connect with the same informations with FileZilla and it works.

So do you know what am i doing wrong ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Generally, getting a "bool given" means the function that produced the value has failed. So here, your `ftp_connect()` has failed, returned `false`, which you then pass into `ftp_login()`.

Comment: "I have to put 22 as port or i have an error." isn't sufficiently detailed for a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @droopsnoot ! But i understood that my connection has failed but i don't understand why because all informations about my server are good...

Comment: @mario if i don't put a port, it will use by default 21 port and my FTP Server is on 22 port

Comment: Somewhat unlikely that port 22 is occupied by a FTP server. See last duplicate listed.